# Has anyone used CoreNLP from stanford for sentiment analysis in Spark? It does not work as desired for me

Tags: apache-spark, twitter, nlp, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

Has anyone used CoreNLP from stanford for sentiment analysis in Spark? 
It is not working as desired or may be I need to do some work which I am not aware of.

Following is the example.

1). I look forward to interacting with kids of states governed by the congress. - POSITIVE 
2). I look forward to interacting with CM of states governed by the congress. - NEGETIVE (CM is chief minister)

Please note the change in one word here. kids -> CM 
Statement 2 is not negetive but coreNLP tagged it as negetive. 
is there anything I need to do to make it work as desired? Any alteration required? Please let me know if I need to plug-in any custom code. 
Whoever has knowledge on this, please suggest something. 
Also, suggest if there is any other better alternate to coreNLP.

Thanks. 
Gaurav

Answer (score 0):

The sentiment model relies on embeddings for all of the words in the statement.  If you change one word you can radically alter the score it will get.  In fact there is a whole area of machine learning research which is analyzing situations like this where you can make changes that don't affect a human's judgment/perception but radically alter the learned model's choices.  For instance in vision problems, there are ways to alter the image that are imperceptible to humans but fool the trained model.

It is important to remember that while a neural network can do impressive things, it is not a perfect replication of the human mind.  Numerous examples like this have been presented to me over the last year, so there clearly are some deficiencies.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this reply. So, what would be the best way to increase the accuracy? How can I train the model so that it gives more accurate results? any pointers towards this would be highly appreciated.